# Redis-Queue (RQ) worker running in the background

Tags: python, redis

I was testing out [RQ](http://python-rq.org/) (Redis-Queue) when after running the command **rqworker** and testing some things out I ended up rebooting my computer without gracefull shuting  down the worker.

Now whether or not I have **rqworker** running there is a constant worker in the background named Ubuntu.4497 in idle state.

Can someone tell me how to gracefully shutdown this worker that seems to be running in the background ?

44497 is not the PID because I cant find anything with the PID 4497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RQ main dev stated that its a bug. https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues/55